# Ember - correct way to get the content value in one controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Apologies for my english,

I am starting to learn ember.js and now i cant read the content property in one controller.
I have one route defined as:

```
App.FilmsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend

model: ->
  App.Film.find()

setupController: (controller, model) ->
   controller.set('content', model)
```

and the controller to this route:

```
App.FilmsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  init: ->
    console.log "entra en films-index"
    console.log @get('content')


  numPeliculas:(->
      @get('length')
    ).property('length')
```

In the view, numPeliculas works perfectly, i get the length of the model resource´s array, but the console doesn´t return the value of content.

how is the correct way to get the content value in one controller ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the controller is initialized, it knows nothing about its content. The `content` property is set in `setupController` after the controller has been initialized.

`@get('content')` is a perfectly fine way to get content inside controller, you just have to do it after you've set the `content` property.